# MySQL: Precision of a Datefield

Tags: mysql

since I have launched a podcast recently I wanted to analyse our Downloaddata. But some clients seem to send multiple requests. So I wanted to only count one request per IP and User-Agent every 15 Minutes. Best thing I could come up with is the following query, that counts one request per IP and User-Agent every hour. Any ideas how to solve that Problem in MySQL?

```
SELECT episode, podcast, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y %k') as blurry_date, useragent, ip FROM downloaddata GROUP BY ip, useragent
```

This is the table I've got

```
CREATE TABLE `downloaddata` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `podcast` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `episode` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filetype` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=216 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd recomend collecting every request, and then only taking one every 15 mins with a distict query, or perhaps counting the number every 15 mins. 
If you are determined to throw data away so it can never be analysed though.
Quick and simple is to just the date and have an int column which is the 15 minute period,
Hour part of current time * 4 + Minute part / 4

DatePart functions are what you want to look up. Things is each time you want to record, you'll have to check if they have in the 15 minute period. Extra work, extra complexity and less / lower quality data...

Answer (score 0):

`MINUTE(date)/15` will give you the quarter hour (0-3). Ensure that along with the date is unique (or ensure `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)/(15*60)` is unique).